# What's the latest version of fglrx on ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, fglrx

I just installed the driver via software sources (fglrx-updates), and fglrxinfo shows that I've got the 9.012 version, which is not the Catalyst 13.4, right? Is the 9.012 the latest version in Ubuntu repositories?
Thanks!

Comment: That's the version I had in Mint 15 install (based on 13.04).